# Notation to indicate input and output dimension of a function

Tags: functions, notation, neural-networks

I have quite a few functions $F_i:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$, where $n$ and $m$ aren't the same for each $F_i$. e.g. $F_0:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$, $F_2:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^4$, etc.

I'm trying to write a composition of some number of $F_i$, say:

$F_5 \circ F_4 \circ F_3 \circ F_2 \circ F_1 \circ F_0 \left(\vec{x}\right)$

I'm wondering if there's a standard/agreed upon way to express the input and output dimensions at each stage of the function composition, something like $F_i^{n\to m}$? It feels clunky to write out the composition and then enumerate "where $F_0:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$, $F_1:\cdots$, etc."

If it helps at all, I'm trying to express an ANN, where each $F_i$ represents the transformation from one layer to another. I thought function composition would be a useful way to reinforce the fact that an ANN is just a nonlinear function (ANNs are not really used in my field so I want to make sure the reader "believes" in my methodology). I thought showing the input and output space could also reinforce the concept that each layer is composed of some number of nodes, but am struggling to find a convenient notation online that does all of this.

Comment: Writing $F_{i}^{n \to m}$ seems no less clunky than $F_i: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, the latter having the advantage of being friendly, familiar, and without a need to explain what it means.  You can always stack things to make it easier to follow:  $X \stackrel{f}{\to} Y \stackrel{g}{\to} Z$.

Comment: Wat about 2 indices like $F_ {m,n}$. Agganging them like this makes composition neat: $F_{n,m}\circ F_{m,k}\circ F_{k,\ell}\circ\cdots$

Comment: The notation Randall ends with is quite common in higher mathematics. So when speaking to mathematicians, it would be understood immediately. For your non-mathematical audience, it would probably be best to give it some explanation though.$$\Bbb R^2 \overset{F_0}{\longrightarrow}\Bbb R^2\overset{F_1}{\longrightarrow}\Bbb R^3\overset{F_2}{\longrightarrow}\Bbb R^4\overset{F_3}{\longrightarrow}\Bbb R^3$$

Comment: Randall and Paul, thank you. That will only take some minor explanation but clearly shows what's going on.